# Visualize Parse Tree Structure

Tags: r, nlp, visualization, igraph, opennlp

I would like to display the parsing (POS tagging) from **openNLP** as a tree structure visualization.  Below I provide the parse tree from **openNLP** but I can not plot as a visual tree common to [Python's parsing](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html#ubiquitous-ambiguity).

```
install.packages(
    "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz",  
    repos=NULL, 
    type="source"
)

library(NLP)
library(openNLP)

x <- 'Scroll bar does not work the best either.'
s <- as.String(x)

## Annotators
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
parse_annotator <- Parse_Annotator()

a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
p <- parse_annotator(s, a2)
ptext <- sapply(p$features, `[[`, "parse")
ptext
Tree_parse(ptext)

## > ptext
## [1] "(TOP (S (NP (NNP Scroll) (NN bar)) (VP (VBZ does) (RB not) (VP (VB work) (NP (DT the) (JJS best)) (ADVP (RB either))))(. .)))"
## > Tree_parse(ptext)
## (TOP
##   (S
##     (NP (NNP Scroll) (NN bar))
##     (VP (VBZ does) (RB not) (VP (VB work) (NP (DT the) (JJS best)) (ADVP (RB either))))
##     (. .)))
```

The tree structure should look similar to this:

[image]

Is there a way to display this tree visualization?

I found [this related tree viz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499140/1000343) question for plotting numeric expressions that may be of use but that I could not generalize to sentence parse visualization.

Comment: Okay, but what after that ?

Comment: Maybe via https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#tikz-qtree ?

Answer (score 10):

Here is an `igraph` version.  This function takes the result from `Parse_annotator` as its input, so `ptext` in your example.  `NLP::Tree_parse` already creates a nice tree structure, so the idea here is to traverse it recursively and create an edgelist to plug into `igraph`.  The edgelist is just a 2-column matrix of head->tail values.

In order for `igraph` to create edges between the proper nodes, they need to have unique identifiers.  I did this by appending a sequence of integers (using `regmatches<-`) to the words in the text prior to using `Tree_parse`.

The internal function `edgemaker` traverses the tree, filling in `edgelist` as it goes.  There are options to color the leaves separately from the rest of the nodes, but if you pass the option `vertex.label.color` it will color them all the same.

```
## Make a graph from Tree_parse result
parse2graph <- function(ptext, leaf.color='chartreuse4', label.color='blue4',
                        title=NULL, cex.main=.9, ...) {
    stopifnot(require(NLP) && require(igraph))

    ## Replace words with unique versions
    ms <- gregexpr("[^() ]+", ptext)                                      # just ignoring spaces and brackets?
    words <- regmatches(ptext, ms)[[1]]                                   # just words
    regmatches(ptext, ms) <- list(paste0(words, seq.int(length(words))))  # add id to words

    ## Going to construct an edgelist and pass that to igraph
    ## allocate here since we know the size (number of nodes - 1) and -1 more to exclude 'TOP'
    edgelist <- matrix('', nrow=length(words)-2, ncol=2)

    ## Function to fill in edgelist in place
    edgemaker <- (function() {
        i <- 0                                       # row counter
        g <- function(node) {                        # the recursive function
            if (inherits(node, "Tree")) {            # only recurse subtrees
                if ((val <- node$value) != 'TOP1') { # skip 'TOP' node (added '1' above)
                    for (child in node$children) {
                        childval <- if(inherits(child, "Tree")) child$value else child
                        i <<- i+1
                        edgelist[i,1:2] <<- c(val, childval)
                    }
                }
                invisible(lapply(node$children, g))
            }
        }
    })()

    ## Create the edgelist from the parse tree
    edgemaker(Tree_parse(ptext))

    ## Make the graph, add options for coloring leaves separately
    g <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist)
    vertex_attr(g, 'label.color') <- label.color  # non-leaf colors
    vertex_attr(g, 'label.color', V(g)[!degree(g, mode='out')]) <- leaf.color
    V(g)$label <- sub("\\d+", '', V(g)$name)      # remove the numbers for labels
    plot(g, layout=layout.reingold.tilford, ...)
    if (!missing(title)) title(title, cex.main=cex.main)
}
```

So, using your example, the string `x` and its annotated version `ptext`, which looks like

```
x <- 'Scroll bar does not work the best either.'
ptext
# [1] "(TOP (S (NP (NNP Scroll) (NN bar)) (VP (VBZ does) (RB not) (VP (VB work) (NP (DT the) (JJS best)) (ADVP (RB either))))(. .)))"
```

Create the graph by calling

```
library(igraph)
library(NLP)

parse2graph(ptext,  # plus optional graphing parameters
            title = sprintf("'%s'", x), margin=-0.05,
            vertex.color=NA, vertex.frame.color=NA,
            vertex.label.font=2, vertex.label.cex=1.5, asp=0.5,
            edge.width=1.5, edge.color='black', edge.arrow.size=0)
```

[image]

Comment: well worth the points I've wanted to be able to do this in R for 3 years.  Just getting back to a package that enables easy parsing and the last piece was that I wanted a  way to plot the parsed sentences.  Can you email me your actual information so I can include you as an author on the package?

Comment: doesn't need to be efficient for now, just working :-)  Even if slow/inefficient it's better than what R has available currently.  I'm going to use your SO handle and reference this question to maintain ethical integrity (i.e., give credit where due).  If you change your mind at any time let me know and I'll use your actual name.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer but note that `i <<- i+1` should switch position with `edgelist[i,1:2] <<- c(val, childval) ` to avoid _subscript out of bounds_ error

Comment: @LIBing are you sure? I haven't run it, but `i` starts from 0 and R indexes from 1