# How can I parse and modify an R expression, possibly using non-standard evaluation?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, pryr

I'd like to parse an R expression into a list and optionally modify aspects of it before finally turning it into a json object.  As an example, I'm trying to get to something like:

```
{"op": "=",
      "content": {
          "lhs": "gender",
          "rhs": ["male"]
      }
}
```

I would be starting with an R expression like:

```
gender == "male"
```

I can use `pryr::ast` to get a text version of the tree, but I'd like to get this as a list like:

```
op: "=="
  [[1]]: "gender"
  [[2]]: "male"
```

The details of the "format" of the list are not so important, just to be clear.  I am simply aiming to get a computable and modifiable parse tree of R expressions.

Comment: I'm thinking the material in this Q&A would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419325/plotting-expression-trees-in-r although it is not focussed on modification of expressions.

Comment: Notice that the pryr functions distinguish true R `names` (aka `symbols`) from mere character values by prepending with backticks. Also note that `quote` is not really included in the lables but that `()` is really substituting for  it. The open parenthesis is an important marker to the R parser and is a function in it own right: `is.function(`\`(`\`)` #[1] TRUE .

Answer (score 5):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
expr <- quote(gender == "male")

expr[[1]]
# `==`
expr[[2]]
# gender
expr[[3]]
# "male"
expr[[3]] <- "female"
expr
# gender == "female"
```

Comment: That is generally it.  I have some more complicated expressions, so I'll need to learn how to work with the nested lists returned by quote, but I think the approach will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach for the output portion of your request, using modifications of the methods cited in my comment. This is based on Hadley's pkg:pryr. See `?Ops` for the list of infix operators. I've seen functions `lhs` and `rhs` defined ... IIRC in Hadley's Advanced Programming text. Obviously the only functions labeled as 'ops' will be the infix math and logical, but a more complete labeling of Math(), Complex(), and Summary() functions could be done with the other lists in the `?groupGeneric` page:

```
call_tree2(quote(gender == "male")) # relabeling of items in pryr-functions
#--------
 - call:
   - `op: ==
   - `gender
   -  "male"
```

Functions defined below:

```
library(pryr) # also loads the stringr namespace
# although the `tree` function is not exported, you can see it with:
pryr:::tree   # now for some hacking and adding of logic
tree2<-
function (x, level = 1, width = getOption("width"), branch = " - ") 
{
    indent <- str_c(str_dup("  ", level - 1), branch)
    if (is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1) {
        label <- paste0(" ", deparse(x)[1])
        children <- NULL
    }
    else if (is.name(x)) {
        x <- as.character(x)
        if (x == "") {
            label <- "`MISSING"
        }
        if (x %in% c("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%%", "%/%",
"&", "|", "!","==", "!=", "<", "<=", ">=", ">") ) {
             label <- paste0("`op: ", as.character(x))}
        else {
            label <- paste0("`", as.character(x))
        }
        children <- NULL
    }
    else if (is.call(x)) {
        label <- "call:"
        children <- vapply(as.list(x), tree2, character(1), level = level + 
            1, width = width - 3)
    }
    else if (is.pairlist(x)) {
        label <- "[]"
        branches <- paste("", format(names(x)), "=")
        children <- character(length(x))
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {
            children[i] <- tree2(x[[i]], level = level + 1, width = width - 
                3, branch = branches[i])
        }
    }
    else {
        if (inherits(x, "srcref")) {
            label <- "<srcref>"
        }
        else {
            label <- paste0("", typeof(x), "")
        }
        children <- NULL
    }
    label <- str_trunc(label, width - 3)
    if (is.null(children)) {
        paste0(indent, label)
    }
    else {
        paste0(indent, label, "\n", paste0(children, collapse = "\n"))
    }
}
environment(tree2)<-environment(pryr:::tree)
```

And now call it with call_tree2:

```
pryr::call_tree
call_tree2 <- 
function (x, width = getOption("width")) 
{
    if (is.expression(x) || is.list(x)) {
        trees <- vapply(x, tree2, character(1), width = width)
        out <- str_c(trees, collapse = "\n\n")
    }
    else {
        out <- tree2(x, width = width)
    }
    cat(out, "\n")
}
environment(call_tree2)<-environment(pryr::call_tree)
```